# My jar file wont run

Tags: java, jar, runtime-error

My sourcecode compiles, and I use this to make my Jar file because I have may images and classfiles:

```
jar cfm Launcher.jar manifest.txt *.class images
jar uf Launcher.jar images/*.png
```

how could I go about finding out why my Jar wont launch? 
When I run the proram from the command prompt, everything works just fine, but when I compile it into a Jar file, it refuses to launch.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I think it's worth mentioning that I've been able to compile my source into a Jar file before and run the program just fine, it was only until recent code that it stopped working. *But I **commented that code out** and it still refused to launch the Jar file.*

Comment: Have you set the main class in the manifest?

Comment: What do you mean by it refuses to launch? Have you specified the main class in MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: I have properly set my main class, yes. I'll edit that in

Comment: Show us what is output when you run those commands.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my output just shows what files were add, and the second command has no output, would you still care to see it?

Comment: Sure, post it. Can't hurt.

Comment: Are you running your jar on the command line? This may be the best way to see any error messages that might occur.

Comment: how would I run it from the command prompt?

Comment: `prompt>java -jar the.jar`  The output might be redirected with a pipe of `|` or `>` e.g. `prompt>java -jar the.jar > op.txt`